# Accessing values in a PS custom object property generated from JSON

Tags: json, powershell, pscustomobject

For a JSON like this:

```
{
"Tours": [{
    "Code": "r",
    "Name": "Tour 1",
    "Tournaments": [{
        "Number": "464",
        "Title": "Open Tournament 1"
    },
    {
        "Number": "047",
        "Title": "Open Tournament 2"
    }]
},
{
    "Code": "s",
    "Name": "Tour 2",
    "Tournaments": [{
        "Number": "524",
        "Title": "Tournament 3"
    },
    {
        "Number": "009",
        "Title": "Tournament 4"
    }]
}]
}
```

when converted to a PS custom object and saved in $data variable, I can access values under 'Tournaments' for specific 'Tours' like this:

```
$data.Tours[0].Tournaments
$data.Tours[1].Tournaments
```

But, is it possible to access 'Tournaments' properties and values by specifying 'Code' or 'Name' values under 'Tours'? Something like that, maybe:

```
$data.Tours.Code['r'].Tournaments
```

Actually, in a PS script I want to filter data by 'Code' under 'Tours' and get underlying 'Tournaments' (get 'Tournaments' for specific 'Code' of the 'Tours').

Comment: `$data.Tours|? Code -eq r|% Tournaments`

Comment: @PetSerAl, thanks! But is it possible to refer to 'Tournaments' directly by using JSON notation and specifying 'r' value for the 'Code' under 'Tour'?

Comment: *refer to 'Tournaments' directly by using JSON notation* Is JSON include some query language like XPath for XML? I am not aware of such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do something like:

```
$data.Tours | Where-Object { $_.Code -eq 'r' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Tournaments'
```

To get the list of concatenated codes and tournament numbers (where the code is "r") you could do:

```
$data.Tours | Where-Object { $_.Code -eq 'r' } | ForEach-Object { $Code = $_.Code; $_.Tournaments | ForEach-Object { $Code + $_.Number }}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I pipe your command to ForEach-Object, will I be able to refer to .Code value from Where-Object? For example, if I need to concatenate 'Code' with 'Tournaments.Number' within ForEach-Object code block.

Comment: Just updated my answer which some code that should do this for you

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, Chris!